# Is there a possibility to create SVN folders from Unix

Tags: unix, svn

Is it possible to automate the process? I don't want to go to svn to create the folders. I want to create them from Unix and later put my scripts and commit them directly from Unix?

Is this possible? I know about the commit process we have `svn commit` .

I'm very new to these things, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking if you can setup SVN repositories without using a subversion client tool? Why?

Comment: You want version control without a server?  You'd be better off to just  use Git.  :P  It beats the pants off Subversion anyway.

Comment: @chao how? Anything specific?

Comment: @bahrep: For one thing, like other DVCSes, it's *made* to work decentralized.  A Git repo is a full repo, with the full revision history and everything.  Branching, merging, committing...it's all local, so it's fast and easy.  And the index gives you an awesome amount of control; you can decide not just which files, but *which changes* in which files you want to commit, whereas `svn commit` just wants to commit everything by default.

Comment: @cHap being decentralized is not a benefit. It just means that the VCS works differently with its own pros and cons. As of Git -- it is not suitable for large projects, teamwork of large teams and for version-controlling binaries. Not to menetion Git's rebase which can be considered as harmful since it shuffles commits. Git is not a silver bullet for VCS, so advising it for everyone is pretty weird.

Comment: @bahrep: When your problem revolves around not wanting to go and create a repo on the server, being decentralized is a *huge* benefit.  I've only seen SVN do two things better than Git -- partial checkouts, and externals/submodules.  Fun part is, Git's fast enough that the former actually isn't all that useful anymore, and there's legacy code where i work that has abused the holy hell out of the latter, so i don't see it as much of a feature anymore.  I don't recommend Git for *everyone*, but it still beats the pants off SVN.

Comment: @cHao H-HOLYWAR~! xD Ok, I won't comment since it's useless in this format. PS One can work with Subversion without any server at all, BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it from command line also

**To create**

```
svnadmin create ~/myrepository
```

**To add**

```
svn add PATH...
```

**To commit**

```
svn commit -m "added tuti."
```

**Reference**

http://www.civicactions.com/blog/2010/may/25/how_set_svn_repository_7_simple_steps

Comment: Hi, Once a directory is created inside the svn repo, How can i commit files to URL from Unix?

Comment: @ramaswamy this link may help you http://masstransmit.com/garage_blog/create-svn-existing-project/